# can I use resourcekey in HTML?

Tags: asp.net, html, multilingual

I wrote an ASP.Net Program that use resource key to support multi language support

Now I want to tokenize this module to enable user give template to it.

for that I give tokens to user to drop it in module and I will replace it. for example if user type [lblsomething] in HTML I will replace it with

```
<span id="lblsomething"> something </span>
```

Now the problem is how can i use resource key with this span to support multi language just like what i have in ASP.Net `<asp:label resourcekey="lblsomething"></asp:label>`

Thanks a lot for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try it in cs:

```
string something=Localization.GetString("KEY" , this.LocalResourceFile);
string html="<span id="lblsomething">"+something+"</span>"
```

and then add html string to page

Comment: Hey atabrizi, your solution is great, Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

You neeed to add runat="server" to the control.

```
<span id="something" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="PressMeButtonResources"/>
```

Or alternatively, you can use **literal control** inside the span tag.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely the solution Localization.GetString... by atabrizi doens't work for me.

This works in my case (example for birthday label + textbox in a form):

```
<label for="birthday">
  <%=GetLocalResourceObject("form_Birthday.Text").ToString()%>
</label>
<input type="text" id="birthday" name="birthday" />
```

[msdn: How to: Retrieve Resource Values Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)