# can I use meta:resourcekey in HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote an ASP.Net Program that uses resource key to support multi language support
The tag below is used in a master page

```
<li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
```

Now the problem is how can I use resource key with the above tag to support multi language just like what I have in ASP.Net `<asp:label resourcekey="lblsomething"></asp:label>`?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755384/asp-net-metaresourcekey

Comment: I tried that but it didnt seem to work though. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid <asp:HyperLink ... /> or <asp:Literal ... />? Both would work with meta:resourcekey.

Comment: Also to make a simple html tag work with meta:resourcekey, you should at least convert it into a server tag, like <a id="RoomsLink" runat="server" href="rooms.html">Rooms</a> (but still not sure if it will work)

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109315/can-i-use-resourcekey-in-html

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text around an `<asp:Label runat="server" meta:resourcekey="" />` web control without affecting the 'a' tag.

All together:

`<li><a href="rooms.html"><asp:Label runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblRoomsLink" /></a></li>`